# Multiple login system with different session time out in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am working on a project in codeigniter and it has 3 different login system eg. admin, sub admin, client. I have to make different session time out for different type of user like admin session time out 5 min. sub admin time out 15 min. and client session time out 30 min.
Any suggestion how to make it happen.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch The User Type from db  and then you can try this.

```
 if ($userType == 'admin')
 {
      //set session for 5 minutes
   $this->session->sess_expiration = '300'; // 5 Minutes
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = 'true';
 }
else if($userType == 'sub_admin'){
  //set session for 15 minutes
   $this->session->sess_expiration = '900'; // 15 Minutes
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = 'true';
}
else
{
  //set session for 30 minutes
  $this->session->sess_expiration = '1800'; //30 Minutes
  $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = 'true';
 }
 $data = array(
              'user_id' => $userdata->user_id,
              'first_name' => $userdata->user_firstname,
            );

  //set session and go to Dashboard or Admin Page
  $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

Comment: have a question: will the session expires after the time of login or the time from last activity

Comment: Thanks man .. That was a great help... Always got confused on which one it is

Comment: Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

this code will do the job

```
if($user['is_admin']) {
    $this->session->sess_expiration = '300'; //5 Minutes
} else if($user['is_sub_admin']) {
    $this->session ->sess_expiration = '900'; //30 Minutes
} else {
    $this->session->sess_expiration = '1800'; //30 Minutes
}
```

just change how are you fetching roles in condition